# Unknown display, low resolution, black screen, nvidia drivers problems

Tags: display, resolution, drivers

I'm having troubles with my display and graphics drivers.

- Can't get my resolution higher than " 1024 * 768 " while my native resolution should be 1980 * 1080. Also it says that it can't recognize my display "Unknown display".
- I have nvidia GeForce 760 oc grapchics card. But as soon I install required drivers and restart my computer it gets ACPI or APCI failed error and leaves me with a black screen.

Would appreciate any help, because I'm not going to use it if it stays like this. Still got my win 8 disk laying around here somewhere :/ Help!

P.S. I will take a look at this thread from time to time, but I use another gmail "lukasblog18@gmail.com", if you can help me out use this gmail to contact me.

Comment: How did you install the "required drivers" you talked about? Did you use the package manager or did you download them from the nvidia website?

Comment: I managed to get my drivers working. All I had to do is to add nomodeset command to grub, but unknown display and low resolution still remains a problem.